# Suppose $|A|=n, f:A\to A$ is injective $\implies \exists k\in [n]:f^k(x)=x$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, functions, graph-theory

[image]

**My Attempt**

**Case 1**

Suppose $f:A \to A$ is an identity function. then $k=1\in [n]:f(x)=x$.

**Case 2**

Suppose $f:A \to A$ is an injective function and non identity function.

so, there exists $x\in A$ such that $f(x) \neq x.$
So, there are $n-1$ possibilities for $f(x).$
if $f(f(x))=x, $ then $k=2.$
so on. I am not able to complete the proof. Is my method correct?

Comment: Hint: The first step will likely be to use the pigeonhole principle to show there are distinct $k, \ell \in \{ 0, 1, \ldots, n \}$ such that $f^{(k)}(a) = f^{(\ell)}(a)$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler could you please explain more. not able to figure out.

Comment: OK, so let's suppose for example you had $f^{(2)}(a) = f^{(5)}(a)$, i.e. $f(f(a)) = f(f(f(f(f(a)))))$.  Can you see what value of $k$ would work in that case?

Comment: *Hint:* $f$ is a bijection

Comment: @DanielSchepler 4. right?

Comment: What is more interesting is to show that there exists an integer $k$ (*not necessarily less than $n$*) such that $f^{(k)}(a)=a$ *for all $a$*.  This is easiest to explain in the language of permutations and the symmetric group.  The proof is effectively the same, also relying on pigeonhole but we instead go up to $n!$ rather than just $n$.

Answer (score 5):

For fixed $a$ we have a chain $$a,f(a), f^2(a),...f^{n}(a)$$ $n+1$ elements from the set with $n$ elements, thus at least two of them are the same, so there are $0\leq i<j\leq n$ such that $$f^i(a) = f^j(a) $$
so $$f^i(a) = f^i(f^{j-i}(a))$$

thus, since $f^i$ is also injective, we have $$a= f^{j-i}(a)$$ and thus $k:=j-i$ does the work.

Answer (score 3):

[This is, at bottom, the answer Daniel gave in the comments]

First note that, since $f$ is injective, there is a function $g:A\to A$ such that for all $x$ in $A$, $(g\circ f)(x)=x$. [In fact, since $A$ is finite, $g$ is actually the inverse function to $f$, but all we need is that $g$ is a left inverse to $f$.]

Now given $a$ in $A$, consider the $n+1$ terms, $a,f(a),f(f(a)),f^{(3)}(a),\dots,f^{(n)}(a)$. These are all elements of the $n$-element set $A$, so two of them must be equal. Let $f^{(i)}(a)=f^{(j)}(a)$ for some $i<j$. Applying $g$ $i$ times, we get $g^{(i)}\circ f^{(i)}(a)=g^{(i)}\circ f^{(j)}(a)$, so $a=f^{(k)}(a)$, where $k=j-i$, and we're done.

Comment: Or, using the injectivity of $f$ directly, you can show that $f^{(i)}(a) = f^{(j)}(a)$ implies $f^{(j-i)}(a) = a$ - for example, by induction on $i$.  The inductive step would be: if $i > 0$, then $f^{(i)}(a) = f^{(j)}(a)$ implies $f(f^{(i-1)}(a)) = f(f^{(j-1)}(a))$, so injectivity of $f$ gives $f^{(i-1)}(a) = f^{(j-1)}(a)$.

Comment: @Daniel yes, I was trying to hide the induction by introducing the one-sided inverse.

Answer (score 2):

For any function $f$ that maps a finite set $A$ to itself, and any initial value $x_0$ in S, the sequence of iterated function values

$$x_{i+1}=f(x_i)$$

must eventually use the same value twice: there must be some pair of distinct indices $i$ and $j$ such that $x_i = x_j$.  One way to visualize this is to construct a graph and a directed arc exists from $i$ to $j$ to $x_j = f(x_i)$, eventually some node must be repeated since there are only finitely many nodes. When we construct such graph, in general, we might get  cycle part plus a chain part that is not in the cycle in general as the cycle need not start at $x_0$. Let $i^*$ be the index where the cycle begins.

Suppose $i^*$ is not equal to $0$ and the period of the cycle is $p$, then we have two preimage of $x_{i^*}$, that is $x_{i^*-1}$ and $x_{i^*-p-1}$, this would violate the injective assumption and hence we conclude that we do not have a chain that is not in the cycle. Hence $S_a = \{f^{k}(x_0): k \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is a cycle.

Hence, we can conclude that there is such a $k$ such that $f^{(k)}(a)=a$ where we just have to pick $k$ to be the period of the cycle.

If we want to prove that a common $k$ can be chosen for all elements, we just have to pick the least common multiple of all the periods of the cycles.

Here is the wikipedia page of Cycle Detection [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection).

Answer (score 1):

Since A is finite and f is injective, f is a permutation (ker (f) = 0). Every permutation in $S_n$ can be writen as a product of disjoint cycles, that is unique up to the ordering of it's cycles and up to a cyclic permutation of it's elements within each cycle. There is a cycle in each orbit of every $a \in A$, and that cycle has at most n elements thus $\implies \forall a \in A,\exists k\in [n]:f^k(a)=a$.

Comment: It does not make sense to talk about $\ker(f)$ in this setting.

Answer (score 0):

Define a graph $G$ with vertices from the set $A$ and two vertices being connected iff one is image of the other.

Clearly each vertex has degree at most 2.

- If all vertices have degree $2$ then this graph is not forest, so exist cycle and thus a conclusion.
- If some vertex $a$ has degree $1$ then $f(a)=a$ and we are done again.